# PHP How to make Curl Request wait for sometime

Tags: php, curl

How can I make curl request that will idle after make request ?

I want to make condition same like user visiting any site then idle for a some time, I want to make that happen in PHP.

Example is, www.siteblalala.com, then I want the php to be idle on that site using curl, how do I make it ?

Comment: take a look at sleep(); [http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Comment: What do you mean by „idle?“ Sleep the PHP process? Let the underlying TCP connection open?

Comment: The condition is like this, example is, I visit google.com, then I stay there for 1 minute, then I close (curl is close connection), how I want to do that ?

Comment: Other example is, IRC robots connect to room, and idle.

So how I can do it with curl and website I want the php to be idle ?

Comment: stay there for 1 minute? sleep() let you wait for 1 minute before visit there again.

Comment: @Cheng Ye : So i have to put sleep before curl_close ?

Comment: put sleep() either before the curl_init or after the curl_close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function:

```
sleep(2); //wait for 2 seconds
```

Description:

> Delays the program execution for the given number of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

try sleep function

```
// sleep for 10 seconds
sleep(10);
```